# Drupal does not show translation on front office but it does on the backoffice

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, translation, drupal-blocks

I have a small issue that I really don't understand. 
I'm working on a multilingual drupal website. In the footer I have a block as full HTML.

[image: Block Default]

When I try to modify it in the backend, it works great for the default language :

[image]

I've entered the translation in backend, and it is saved in the backend. But when I go on the translated page, the modification is not taken into account.

[image: Block english after translation]

Do you have any idea why this is ? I have tried to remove cache from drupal, but nothing changed.

Thank you 
Thoma

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenue (Welcome) in the world of multilanguage sites ... Below are some possible reasons that are causing your issue ...

## Language Detection?

Your problem might be because of the "language detection" configuration.

So check this configuration via *Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection*: the order should be 'URL, Default, User', and not something like 'Default, URL, User'.

## Block translation?

Submodule `i18n_block`, included in the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module could be what you're looking for ... or at least address part of your question.

Some more details about it:

> This module provides support for multilingual blocks.
>
> You can set up a language for a block or define it as translatable:
>
> - Blocks with a language will be displayed only in pages with that language.
> - Translatable blocks can be translated using the localization interface.

## What else?

If none of the above helps, then consider editing your question to better explain:

1. What is your default language? I "guess" you're using language 'en' (English) and 'fr' (`French), but guessing what the question really is makes it difficult to answer them correctly ...
2. What exactly the change/modification is that you did (I do see translated text like "Join us on ...")
3. Front office, backoffice, backend, ... try to rephrase those terms in Drupal specific terminology. Where possible also including links link `/admin/...`

Comment: Great Advice from Pierre, this may also be better off in your theme and surrounded with t() anything within a t() tag is passed through Drupals Text Replacement/Translator function.

Comment: Thank you @DanielWaters , I do agree that using 't()' for all text is what you should be doing. But putting a translation in a Theme would imply that you have to start over (not forget ...) the same work whenever you change themes, no? That's why I personally never put anything translation related in themes. But of course, in Drupal there are often multiple ways to get things done ...